# Using different deployment targets to executed multiple 'Deploy a Release' steps in a project

Tags: octopus-deploy

I am having 3 “Deploy a Release” steps in a Octopus project. I need to deploy each steps in a different Azure WebApp. How can achieve the this.

For example I have an octopus project named ‘Fruit’, and I have 3 steps in the project, each one to “Deploy a Release”

Step 1: Apple - To be deployed on an Azure Web-app ‘Alpha’ in Dev Environment.

Step 2: Orange - To be deployed on an Azure Web-app ‘Bravo’ in Dev Environment.

Step 3: Mango - To be deployed on an Azure Web-app ‘Charlie’ in Dev Environment.

All the azure web apps are under the same account. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you will be having separate package feeds (alpha package,...) for each steps, you should be able to achieve deployment to each web app in same environment by using variables scoped to each specific step.
[variable scoping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVLUv.png)

Comment: You should be able to just exclude each step from the environments it should not be in.